# A counter-example to disprove that not every adjacency matrix can be made block-diagonal?

Tags: graph-theory, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices, clustering, hermitian-matrices

I have a bunch of clusters of proteins (a disconnected graph) and wanted to present this data as an adjacency matrix for various reasons and have been looking for a way to **make these adjacency matrices block-diagonal** to make the relationships more apparent, but had no luck. I have tried [SciPy's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) reverse [Cuthill-McKee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm), svd, [somebody has recommended Dulmage-Mendehlson](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34886/what-is-the-algorithm-to-convert-an-adjacency-matrix-to-a-block-diagonal-structu) and a bunch of other decompositions but to no avail. By this point, somebody told me that this might not even be possible in every case.

**Would somebody happen to have an example or a concrete formulation of why exactly?** I can't quite convince myself that's it's not possible from just looking at my data which looks like this by the way... Clearly, the structures which I'm trying to present are there (the *large* and *small* ribosomal subunits) and would probably become more apparent when I pour more data in there, but I would've so loved to also differentiate the clusters within the two subunits because I know they are there. Should I just use a covariance matrix?

[image]

Here is what breadth-first search yields by the way. Still I am not sure what that means, but I can definitely see now that permuting *out of* this state of band-minimization breaks structure rather than builds it, so maybe that's as far as I get today.

[image]

Comment: Possibly useful [MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68041/showing-block-diagonal-structure-of-matrix-by-reordering).

Comment: There are apparently two clusters between indices $[0, 30]$ and $[60, 80]$ in your original matrix, this is quite visible. However, there are also two entries on row 30 / columns 70 and 80. I think that these entries may connect the two clusters.
Indeed, the result of your BFS (which is just a permutation of the rows and columns) shows a connected graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always can permute the rows and columns of the adjacency matrix so that each block corresponds to a connected component.  Just find the connected components and then reorder with all nodes from component 1 first, component 2 next, and so on.

Comment: Any idea which algorithm I can use to do that or what's the trick if I were to do it manually? Maybe i'm missing something very basic, but let's say if I run another 10 molecules through my code and it turns out that the clusters( interior to the subunits ) are arranged a bit differently than what it is here, do i permute the namespace(rows and columns = protein names) again?

Comment: Breadth-first search, depth-first search, union-find are three choices to find the connected components.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions:

1. What do the colors in your plots represent?
2. How can you be sure your graph is disconnected if you haven't block-diagonalized its adjacency matrix?  Is there something in the nature of the data that guarantees this?

Now some comments:

If your graph really does have $n$ disconnected components, than its adjacency matrix certainly can be written in block diagonal form with $n$ blocks, regardless of what anybody says.

Something like the following should work.  Let `A` be an `m` by `m` adjacency matrix.  Create an array `componentIdentifier` of length `m`, with every element initialized to 0.  Also create an array `permutation` of length `m`.

```
numberComponents = 0
numberVerticesPermuted = 0
for i from 1 to m:
   if componentIdentifier[i] == 0:
      /* vertex i is in a new component */
      numberComponents = numberComponents + 1
      componentIdentifier[i] = numberComponents
      numberVerticesPermuted = numberVerticesPermuted + 1
      permutation[numberVerticesPermuted] = i

      /* find all vertices connected to i */
      k = numberVerticesPermuted
      while k <= numberVerticesPermuted:
         r = permutation[k]
         for c from 1 to m:
            if A[r,c] == 1 and componentIdentifier[c] == 0:
               componentIdentifier[c] = numberComponents
               numberVerticesPermuted = numberVerticesPermuted + 1
               permutation[numberVerticesPermuted] = c
         k = k + 1
```

When this concludes, `numberComponents` will hold the number of disconnected components and `permutation` will hold the permutation of indices needed to put the adjacency matrix in block-diagonal form.

Comment: Thank you, Will! I will try this right away...
The colors in these plots I provided are actually multiple adjacency matrices summed element-wise and then divided by the number of matrices. ( To emulate the "mean of 
a population graphs", i realize there are more sophisticated methods out there.) So the brightest spots are the proteins that co-occur in space in multiple molecules.
I think i can guarantee disconnectedness because of how i defined my clusters: any neighbor of $n$'th neighbor belongs to the same cluster. Maybe a spanning forest is a technical term. And I actually have the graph